# Is there any way to create 2 (or more) view objects from the same view class and dynamically configure WPF XAML data bindings in them?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, binding

I currently have a WPF application where there is a single view that displays chart information from the view model.  The view is heavily data bound to the view model for both its data and its configuration settings.  I would like to create 2 more views using the same view model so that I can see different parts of the data at the same time.

The chart has up to 30 series on them and each series has bindings for its: data, color, thickness, marker size, etc.

Currently I have something like this for the bindings:
Value="{Binding ConfigSettings.Chart1Series01Thickness}"

I have successfully copied and pasted the view code, renamed everything that references Chart1 to Chart2 and now have 2 charts working.

I would much rather have and support a single view class that somehow allows different data bindings when it’s created. I can easily pass in a chart number when the view is created but have no idea how it could/should be used to control the data bindings.

Example;

When view 1 is created pass in the number 1 so that it uses a binding like this:
Value="{Binding ConfigSettings.Chart_1_Series01Thickness}"

When view 2 is created pass in the number 2 so that it uses a binding like this:
Value="{Binding ConfigSettings.Chart_2_Series01Thickness}"

I’m not sure if anything like this is even possible or if there is a more elegant solution.

(A single working example is worth a thousand words.)

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Here is some additional clarification:

What I would like to do is use the same view class instanced 3 times without any code or xaml changes between them.  Each chart has over a hundred properties that are persisted to XML between application run and that is in addition to all of the shared properties.

So when I create each of the view objects I am looking for a way to tell then to use its unique set of configuration properties in addition to all of the other properties that are shared between the different views, all of these properties are in the view model.

I would like to do this by passing something to the views constructor.  Any changes to the actual view class to obtain this will require that each view is a class in a separate file and that is where I am now.

So in short I am trying to create 3 separate view objects from the same view class, accessing the same view model and have them work differently based on something passed to its constructer.

Currently I am looking into refactoring the view model so that I could provide a base data context for what’s common between the views and also have unique data contexts which are needed for each view.

I would then pass into the views constructor a unique data context that applies only to those settings that need to be different.  This may work but it seems very convoluted and I am hoping someone has a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite simple: expose a  `CurrentChart` property that changes in tandem to a `CurrentChartSettings` property in your viewmodel.

your code becomes then:

```
Value="{Binding CurrentChartSettings.Series01Thickness}"
```

Or better still: make the `CurrentSettings` a property of the `CurrentChart` itself.

```
Value="{Binding CurrentChart.CurrentSettings.Series01Thickness}"
```

EDIT: A more eleborate example, a fully working application:

The XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<UniformGrid>
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Texts}"
              SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentText}"/>
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding FontSizes}"
              SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentFontSize}"/>
    <TextBlock FontSize="{Binding CurrentFontSize}" Text="{Binding CurrentText}"/>
</UniformGrid>
```

The code behind and the Viewmodel:

```
Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel
Imports System.ComponentModel

Class MainWindow

Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()

    Dim viewModel = New ViewModel
    viewModel.Texts = New ObservableCollection(Of String)
    viewModel.Texts.Add("Hello")
    viewModel.Texts.Add("World")

    viewModel.FontSizes = New ObservableCollection(Of Integer)
    viewModel.FontSizes.Add(8)
    viewModel.FontSizes.Add(16)
    viewModel.FontSizes.Add(32)
    viewModel.CurrentFontSize = viewModel.FontSizes.First

    Me.DataContext = viewModel
End Sub
End Class

Public Class ViewModel
Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

Public Property Texts As ObservableCollection(Of String)

Public Property FontSizes As ObservableCollection(Of Integer)

Private _currentText As String
Public Property CurrentText As String
    Get
        Return _currentText
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        If value = _currentText Then Return
        _currentText = value
        RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs("CurrentText"))
    End Set
End Property

Private _currentFontSize As Integer
Public Property CurrentFontSize() As Integer
    Get
        Return _currentFontSize
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Integer)
        If _currentFontSize = value Then Return
        _currentFontSize = value
        RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs("CurrentFontSize"))
    End Set
End Property

Public Event PropertyChanged(sender As Object, e As PropertyChangedEventArgs) Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged
End Class
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. If I understand correctly, this is similar to what I am currently doing and I end up with multiple classes to get multiple views.  Start with the original view, copy and paste into 2 more views, edit the 2 new views to uses the correct properties, etc.  This works and gives me multiple views on the same view model but not from the same class template.  I have edited the original question in the hope that it is clearer.

Comment: You did not understand correctly :-) The xaml does not have to change. You define a collection of Charts and ChartProperties in your viewmodel and select one of them to become Current. Call PropertyChanged and you are all set.

Comment: I still do not see how this can work.  All my views and view models are active at the same time.

Let’s say I have the following view and view model classes:

The view class has only one text box data bound to a single view model property.

The view model class has 2 different text properties (prop1 and prop2)

How do I create 2 view objects from the same view class where the first view object binds to the prop1 property and the second view object binds to prop2.

Comment: The only solution I can see is to either create 2 different view classes or 2 different view model classes.  If your one line solution solves this, I for the life of me do not understand how.

Comment: I added a more elaborate example. In this example the different viewmodels are selected from the view itself, but this is not necessary. I can be done from other code too.

Comment: I really appreciate you taking the time to answer but you do not seem to understand my question.  Your code is what I’m currently doing.  I’m not sure if I can be any clearer but I will try.
2 classes – 1 for the view and 1 for the vm.
3 objects created from the 2 classes – 2 views and 1 vm all instanced and in use at the same time.
If the vm has 2 properties called prop1 and prop2 is there any way to get the data bindings in view 1 to bind to prop1 and the data binding in view 2 to bind to prop 2 by passing something into the view constructor to point them in the right place?

Comment: @user1771706 Sorry, I pass.